# What legitimate purpose does being able to write to other processes' memory and execute threads there have in Windows?

Tags: windows, assembly

Seriously, VirtualAllocEx, WriteProcessMemory and CreateRemoteThread all allow functionality that for the life of me I cannot figure out the reason to have.

Any inter-process stuff I can think of with legitimate purposes could be done by exporting libraries etc..

I would love an explanation of why this kind of thing is allowed in Windows.

Comment: They are for debuggers. Otherwise, how would a debugger set a breakpoint or evaluate an expression?

Comment: Patching into another process still doesnt make sense...even for GUI debuggers they could read the binary, convert to shellcode, execute it as their own process, and breakpoints could be done with code patching on a process that you own rather than patching into someone else's process. Is that wrong?

Comment: Yes, you're wrong. You'd have to bring in the entire debugged process in the debugger process, including all code and data, and the entire OS per-process state including things like open files, and obviously that can't work. Also "shellcode" doesn't mean what you think it does. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellcode

Comment: As Raymond Chen posted, it's for debuggers. I think there are only 2 hardware breakpoints, so code injection is needed to replace opcodes with the singly byte INT 3 instruction if more than two breakpoints are needed. Debuggers usually allow a user to change memory (like variables) while stepping through code. "Trainers" identify themselves as debuggers, so there's virtually no client side protection for Windows to prevent the usage of trainers. For some games, cheat detection is limited to "sanity" checks on the server side, assuming that sufficient information is sent to the host.

Comment: Note that even Visual Studio's debugger can "attach" to a running process, pause the process, set breakpoints, and modify code or data within that process. So it can even be used as a crude "trainer".

Comment: even on Linux gdb can attach to any running processes to debug

Comment: what do you mean by "legitimate" purpose? If the computer owner wants to modify other process memory, why shouldn't they be allowed to? It's their computer, none of your business... (I mean, if I own a computer, where this is possible on HW level, and the OS would not allow me, and I would need it, I would either replace the OS or modify it to allow it, wouldn't simply accept it, my computers are my general purpose calculators and I'm using them to calculate whatever I like, I would not even buy HW+OS where I can't use it as I wish)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you count this as a legitimate purpose or nor, but I use those for code injection into processes I launch.

First, the process is started with the main thread suspended using CreateProcess. Then the parameters for LoadLibrary are written to the memory of that process and CreateRemoteThread is used to create a new thread calling LoadLibrary.

Now you have loaded your own dll into the process you started, and you can resume its main thread.

This is useful for e.g. analyzing or modifying the behavior of the program.

Comment: [Event Tracing for Windows (ETW)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/etw/event-tracing-portal) is the built-in infrastructure for analyzing applications. While this works for applications that haven't been instrumented, gathering custom information usually requires that the target application is instrumented.